# Limit input method to camera capture only

Tags: camera, input-type-file

Using file type, and accept attribute,, is there any way to restrict input method to camera only and avoid uploading from library.

Answer (score -1):

seems like there is no way to do that for html. on desktop browser, it will always open the file upload window.

Answer (score -2):

The capture attribute of input tag does the magic here.

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture />
```

Reference:
 [HTML Media Capture Examples](http://anssiko.github.io/html-media-capture/)

[input](/questions/tagged/input)   [camera](/questions/tagged/camera)  [file](/questions/tagged/file)  [capture](/questions/tagged/capture)  [html](/questions/tagged/html)   [mediadevices](/questions/tagged/mediadevices)  [enumeratedevices](/questions/tagged/enumeratedevices)